# Where to place glue tabs when creating pockets?

Tags: print-design, print-production, packaging, dieline, diecut

When creating mechanicals for folders with pockets, where should one set the glue tabs--on the smaller flap for the pocket or on the main body of the piece and why?

Or is this decided on a case by case basis with other factors affecting placement?

If so, what are these factors?

Comment: I can't quite remember specifications for glue areas, though I think it may be .5mm from the edge of the pocket attachment. Hopefully someone will come along with a proper answer :)

Comment: you need to ask the people that are making the folders for you

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, these things are often done manually, and a double face tape "gun" will be used to apply the glue. So it's not always glue but a tape that is used.

The glue usually goes on the smaller flaps because it's easier to measure its length and ensure it won't be visible at all.

Most printers prefer that flap to be at least 5/8" (0.625") since the tapes are often 0.25"-0.5" width. You should leave the area where the tape/glue will be in white, it will stick better!

But if you are working on a project that will be printed in huge quantities (eg. 5000+), the best is probably to ask the printer; it's possible they will use a mechanical process for this and will have different requirements (and more precision too).

The flap where the glue will be applied is usually on the pocket panel.

[image: folder dieline design]

**EXTRA:** Anyway, if you are using a standard kind of folder, your printer will use a diecut he already has on hand and you should base your design on this dieline. Simply ask the printer for that dieline file.

---

Related:

[drawing diecut line for chipboard and wrapping paper to form boxes](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/63944/drawing-diecut-line-for-chipboard-and-wrapping-paper-to-form-boxes/63954#63954)

[How should I set up dielines so that they are not printed?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28253/how-should-i-set-up-dielines-so-that-they-are-not-printed/58558#58558)

Image source:

http://foldersunlimited.com/product/plain-white-folders/

Comment: oops. I should clarify. I actually mean where should the flap be designed for the glue tape. Should the flap be part of the pocket flap or part of the main panel?

Comment: @Chung It should be part of the pocket flap! It's easier to hide any small misalignment this way and it also looks better when looking at the folded pocket from the front.